# How to catch error in googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-id'); });?

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I am trying to catch the error on

```js
 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-id'); });
```

While I know the root of the problem is because the slot is not defined in the head, how can I catch the error? I'm facing a problem where the definedSlot is messy and all over the place so I think catching the error in the googletag.cmd.push would be an easier solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check wether the targeted ID in the googletag defined slots exists in the DOM before displaying it :

```
    //get all the defined slots
    var definedSlots = googletag.pubads().getSlots();
    //loop through the definedSlots
    for (var x = 0; x < definedSlots.length; x++) {
       //retrieve the targeted ID
       var slotId = definedSlots[x].getSlotId().getDomId();
       //if it exists
       if (document.querySelector('#'+ slotId)) {
          //then dislay it
          googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(slotId); });
       }
     }
```